# How import multiple sheet Excel from PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a file Excel contains 4 sheets. I imported just the first sheet but I want to import all the 4 sheets.

This is my code:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader(PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filePath));
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filePath);    
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
    /*echo $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getCalculatedValue();
    echo $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $row)->getCalculatedValue();
    echo $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$row)->getCalculatedValue();*/
    $listEquipement[] = new Article(
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getCalculatedValue(),
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getCalculatedValue(),
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, $row)->getCalculatedValue()
);

}       
return $listEquipement;
```

I found that I can use : `getActiveSheet()` by adding replace this line:

```
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
```

By this:

```
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, null, true, false);
```

Is this solution true ? Can someone help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well you tell us! Does that work?

Comment: Really I don't know, not yet I test it, I'm afraid change my database, I want verify with you firstly. You confirm it I think according your answer ?